# using partial differentiation to find second order derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$x^2-4xy+5y^2=2$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$
 $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-2y}{2x-5y}$ 
i believe there are many ways to find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{F_{xx}F_{y}^2-2F_{xy}F_{x}F_{y}+F_{yy}F_{x}^2}{F_{y}^3}=\frac{2(-4x+10)^2+8(2x-4y)(-4x+10y)+10(2x-4y)^2}{(4x-10y)^3}$
i try this way and i multiplied all things in the bracket but i 
cant find this result $=\frac{2}{(2x-5y)^3}$

can someone give me hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found that $y' = \dfrac{x-2y}{2x-5y}\implies \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}= y'' = \dfrac{(1-2y')(2x-5y) - (x-2y)(2-5y')}{(2x-5y)^2} = \dfrac{2x-5y-4xy'+10yy'-2x+5xy'+4y-10yy'}{(2x-5y)^2}=\dfrac{-y+xy'}{(2x-5y)^2}= \dfrac{-y+x\cdot \dfrac{x-2y}{2x-5y}}{(2x-5y)^2}=\dfrac{x^2-4xy+5y^2}{(2x-5y)^3}$

Comment: thankyou so much. i think using quotient rule is the simplest way. thankyou so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-4xy+5y^2=2$ with implicit derivative:
$$2x-4y-4xy'+10y'y=0$$
shows $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x-2y}{2x-5y}$ and then derivative gives:
$$2-4y'-4y'-4xy''+10y'^2+10y''y=0$$
or
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{x^2-4xy+5y^2}{(2x-5y)^3}$$

Comment: thankyou so much!! i also tried using implicit differentiation but really need to be careful